# How to pass data from ng-view to navbar located at index.html in Agularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, mean-stack

I just started learning the MEAN stack and am trying to build an authentication page from scratch (even though I know I could use the out of the box authentication but am doing this to have a background understanding) but am finding it a bit tricky to update texts on my navbar.
My `index.html` looks like this;

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" ng-controller="HeadController">
 <div class = "container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a href="#">{{user.name}}</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
<div class="container" ng-view></div>
```

My `app.js` looks like this;

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute'])
     .service("userService", function () {
         this.user = {};
         this.getUser = function () {
            return this.user;
         };
         this.setUser = function (user) {
            this.user = user;
         };
      })
      .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
         $routeProvider
           .when('/login', {
               templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
               controller: 'LoginCtrl as login'
            })
           .when('/user/profile',{
              templateUrl: 'partials/profile.html',
              controller: 'ProfileCtrl as profile'
           })
           .otherwise({
               redirectTo: '/login'
            });
      }]);
   app.controller("HeadController", [
      '$scope',
      'userService',
      function ($scope, userService) {
       $scope.user = userService.getUser();
   }]);
  app.controller("LoginCtrl", [
      "$location",
      "userFactory",
      "userService",
      function ($location, userFactory, userService) {
         var login = this;
         login.user = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            isRemember: true
         };
         login.login = function () {
            userFactory.login(login.user)
               .success(function (user) {
                  userService.setUser(user);
                  $location.path("/user/profile");
               })
               .error(function (err) {
                  console.log(err);
               });
         };
   }]);
```

finally, my `userFactory.js` looks like this;

```
 function login(user) {
            return $http({
               url: '/api/login/',
               method: "POST",
               data: user,
               headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
               }
            });
         }
return{login:login};
```

Whenever I login, I expect `{{user.name}}` be updated but that doesn't happen. I don't know how to get this done. What can I do to make this happen?

Comment: given that you are starting new.. use components and component based routing.. it would be easier to understand...

Comment: @entre Please can you be kind enough to explain?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `userService.setUser(user)` replaces the services's reference in memory to the "user" object after the previous user object (and reference in memory) had been bound to the $scope of `HeadController`. There are few ways to fix this:

**1.** Mutate (instead of replacing) the original object with `setUser`:

```
this.setUser = function(newUserData) {
  angular.extend(this.user, newUserData);
};
```

**2.** Make a dynamic reference to "name" in your template

```
<li><a href="#">{{ userService.getUser().name }}</a></li>
```

**3.** (the preferred choice IMO, although definitely not the easiest to implement) Make custom event handlers in your user service so that when you call `setUser`, callback "listeners" will get invoked. This would allow you to do something like this in `HeadController`:

```
userService.onUserUpdate(function(newUser) {
  $scope.user = newUser; // or userService.getUser();
});
```

and to keep the template/view cleaner and more declarative, the way you currently have it:

```
<li><a href="#">{{ user.name }}</a></li>
```

This can be implemented like this. In `userService` add:

```
var privateUserUpdateListeners = [];   

this.onUserUpdate = function(cb)
  if (angular.isFunction(cb)) {
    privateUserUpdateListeners.push(cb);
    // Return a callback that can be used to deregister the listener.
    // In production code, you may want to wrap this function
    // to ensure that it may only get called once.
    return function() {
      var index = privateUserUpdateListeners.indexOf(cb);
      privateUserUpdateListeners.splice(index, 1);
    };
  }
};

this.broadcastUserUpdate = function(user) {
  privateUserUpdateListeners.forEach(function(cb) {
    cb(user);
  });
};
```

Then in `setUser` you could add a broadcast like:

```
this.setUser = function(user) {
  this.user = user;
  this.broadcastUserUpdate(user);
};
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Please can you kindly give a brief code snippet on your preferred choice? (that is solution #3).

Comment: @OchiFortune lemme know if that makes. If you have trouble wrapping head around it (I know I did at first) and interested, you might want to google JavaScript observer pattern.

Comment: It makes sense but not quit. I tried applying it but still didn't solve it. I will appreciate a working example like on plurk. Thanks btw